# OpenERP - XML - How to hide the report tag?

Tags: xml, report, odoo

I have to show/hide a report tag in a report.xml file depending on the state of the object, but the following code does not work, when I update de OpenERP module, it shows me an error message:

```
openerp Invalid attribute attrs for element report
```

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <report
        auto="False"
        id="partidas_contralor"
        model="grp.account.partidas.contralor.header"
        name="grp.account.partidas.contralor.header"
        rml="grp_partidas_contralor/report/partidas_contralor.rml"
        string="Imprimir partida contralor"
        header="True"
    />

    <report
        auto="False"
        id="declaracion_jurada"
        model="grp.account.partidas.contralor.header"
        name="grp.declaracion_jurada_partidas_print"
        rml="grp_partidas_contralor/report/declaracion_jurada.rml"
        string="Imprimir declaración jurada"
        header="True"
        attrs="{'invisible':[('state','!=','draft')]}"
    />

</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: `<report>` tag don't have attribute name `attrs`. `<report>` tag with model, it will show menu in all state of that model. If you want to archive your requirement than you can make a `button` on that it will print report.

Comment: Hello, do you have solution this problem?. Different from button. I have same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868643/how-to-call-a-xlsx-report-from-button-in-odoo

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this in openERP 7.

Here you can find full documentation for reports: https://doc.odoo.com/6.1/developer/05_reports/

One way to work around it is to set header="False", with this you hide report in header and set menu=False so report won't appear anywhere.
Then create button that calls that report (action) and on that button you can set attr.

Example:

```
<button name="%(partidas_contralor)d" 
        type="action" 
        string="Button action name" 
        class="oe_highlight" 
        attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'draft')]}" 
/>
```

One more thing to mention, sometimes attribute header doesn't hide report...